# Laravel 5.6 Auth from two different tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I would like to ask about logging in to Laravel but in a different way:
User information including the password but not the email will be stored in `users table`, while email_address will be stored in a `email_addresses table` with a boolean field called `is_default`.

So the user can have several emails, but he can log in with only one email that has the `is_default` is `true`. and he could change his default email through his profile.

So, how can I make the login process through the Auth::login() facade.

I was able to register the user by storing the information in a `users table` and store his `email_address and is_default = true` in the `email_addresses table`.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a little tricky. `Auth::login()` just needs to fetch email and password, so if you can trick the model into thinking it has an email field accessible via `$user->email`, things will work out:

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
{
  return DB::table('email_addresses')->whhere('default', 1)->where('user_id', $this->id)->first()->toArray()['email'];
}
```

Comment: In which file would I add this function?

Comment: User.php, the User model

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work, in fact, it checks the `email_address` and the `password` from the `users` table, then it checks the existence of the `email_address` from the `email` table.
While it shouldn't have an `email_address` in the `users` table altogether.

Comment: yes, it DOES check the users table itself. as I said, it's just a trick. but if at the end, the real email from emails table is checked, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it does check the email_address from the other table after it checks the username and password from the user table, which means it rejects the login before it checks the email from the other table.

Comment: What I mean, I have to have a field called email_address in the users table (which I don't have), and the email_address should be their and once the username and password is correct then it checks the email_address from the other table and if the is_default is false for the email_address of the other table then it logs in normally since the email_address and password is correct in the users table.

Comment: try adding the __get method then. public function __get($name){if($name=='email') return $emailFromOtherTable; else parent__get($name);}

Comment: @FatemehMajd same issue here, your solution had the same problem. Keeps giving the Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' error